# Text file importing in R

Tags: r, text, import

I'm currently stuck while trying to import this text file data set because of the giant white spaces. I'm currently using the read_table2 function, but it seems that the function skips over huge white spaces. For example, if my columns were number grade and town, sometimes I will see values for town in the column grade for a specific observation.

Please help me!

This is a picture of the dataset.

[image: This is a picture of the dataset]

Comment: it seems that your data is fixed width, and `readr::read_table2` is made for space delimited files. try `read.fwf`

Comment: Please provide data as plain text, or the output of `dput()`, or as a link to an easily-accessible file, not as an image.